# Add module to Component area

Tags: module, templates, joomla-3.9

My main menu is linking category blog which is automatically displayed in component area, and I want to put a slider module in component area too, but only in home page, so modules on "Right" position would be right next to the slider.

I was reading this post: [How to display module in component area](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/how-to-display-module-in-component-area)

But I don't understand in which file should I put code samples.

Is it possible to make this?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Mateo.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Answer (score 0):

when you are talking about the default joomla category blog checkout how to do a template override - there you can enter your custom position.

a good point to start: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

remember : Never edit core files directly